# Word for a feeling about something you weren't supposed to see

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that describes the feeling of seeing/knowing something that you weren't supposed to. Like learning someone's secret or reading their diary. I think I recall there being a word that describes this feeling but I can't find it anywhere. I'm thinking something similar to "guilt", but more specific.

Comment: Welcome! For the “-request” tags, we ask that you include a sample sentence showing how the word would be used. This helps narrow down parts of speech and context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**abashed** (adj.)

> Feeling or caused to feel discomfited or disconcerted, esp. as a
> result of a sudden sense of shame or embarrassment. OED

> Made to feel uncomfortable, disconcerted, or embarrassed by something
> that has happened or been done or said
>
> *I stood back, abashed, wondering what I'd done wrong.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abashed)

> Embarrassed, disconcerted, or ashamed. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/abashed)

*Abashed* is broader in meaning than *ashamed* and *embarrassed*, as the definitions show. You might feel ashamed for reading someone's diary and perhaps embarrassed or uncomfortable, but not ashamed, if you are cc'd by mistake on an email that contains revealing personal information.

---

> He doesn't give her time to stop him. 'I read her diary.'
> Angie groans. 'Oh, Dad. You didn't.
> He's **abashed**. 'I know. I didn't meant
> to—well, I suppose I did, but I didn't know what I was looking for.
> Anything that shed some light.' [Paul Carroll; *Don't Ask*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Don_t_Ask/dncpEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=abashed%20%20read%20diary&pg=PA247&printsec=frontcover)

> It is perhaps unfortunate that the only personal reign known to the
> public should have included all the major failures of our intelligence
> service; but Sir Percy is not **abashed** at this unfortunate
> coincidence. [Hugh Trevor-Roper and E.D. Harrison; *The Secret World:
> Behind the Curtain of British Intelligence*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Secret_World/Od3kDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=abashed%20%20learning%20secret&pg=PA153&printsec=frontcover)

> The Barber looked greatly **abashed** at this rebuke, and a little
> alarmed at the notion of learning so deep a mystery, and the two
> walked along in a solemn silence. [S. N. Cleghorn, D. C. Fisher;
> *Fellow Captains*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fellow_Captains/p1YPAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=abashed%20%20learning%20secret&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: ***Abashed*** is good for OP's context, but [***ashamed*** is far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28I+was+abashed%29%2B%28I+felt+abashed%29%2C%28I+was+ashamed%29%2B%28I+felt+ashamed%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28I%20was%20abashed%29%20%2B%20%28I%20felt%20abashed%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28I%20was%20ashamed%29%20%2B%20%28I%20felt%20ashamed%29%3B%2Cc0) and just as good, imho. Better, really, for a *learner's* site (why would a learner want to be encouraged to use the less common of two near-synonyms?).

Comment: Oops! My mistake! I'd started my browser window on ELL, but failed to notice when commenting here that I'd somehow switched over to ELU